# Join two tables but only get most recent associated record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time constructing an sql query that gets all the associated data with respect to another (*associated*) table and loops over into that set of data on which are considered as latest (*or most recent*).

The image below describes my two tables (*Inventory and Sales*), the Inventory table contains all the item and the Sales table contains all the transaction records.  The Inventory.Id is related to Sales.Inventory_Id.  And the **Wanted result** is the output that I am trying to work on to.

My objective is to associate all the sales record with respect to inventory but only get the most recent transaction for each item.

[image]

Using a plain join (*left, right or inner*) doesn't produce the result that I am looking into for I don't know how to add another category in which you can filter the most recent data to join to.  Is this doable or should I change my table schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Select Item,Sales.Price
From Inventory I
     Cross Apply(Select top 1 Price
                 From Sales S
                 Where I.id = S.Inventory_Id
                 Order By Date Desc) as Sales
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select Item, Price
  from Inventory i 
    inner join Sales s 
      on i.id = s.Inventory_Id
        and s.Date = (select max(Date) from Sales where Inventory_Id = i.id)
```

Comment: This resulted to a single row, which displays the item with the most recent Date.

Comment: @ChiSen Oh sorry, try with the subquery on the join condition instead (as shown in edit).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Sales_Latest AS (
  SELECT *,
    MAX(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Inventory_Id) Latest_Date
  FROM Sales
)
SELECT i.Item, s.Price
FROM Inventory i
INNER JOIN Sales_Latest s ON (i.Id = s.Inventory_Id)
WHERE s.Date = s.Latest_Date
```

Think carefully about what results you expect if there are two prices in Sales for the same date.

Comment: There should only be one price for an item for a particular date.

Comment: @ChiSen In theory, "There should only be one price."  In reality, you either have a UNIQUE constraint, or you *will* have more than one price.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
  select i.name, 
         row_number() over (partition by i.id order by s.date desc) as rownum,
         s.price,
         s.date
  from inventory i
  left join sales s on i.id = s.inventory_id
) tmp
where rownum = 1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7241/6)